# Angular vs phonegap get trouble when building in android platform

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

I develop an application by angular js after that i use phonegap vs cordova to build this in android platform. However, when i start building this, in logCat windows show many error "Unknown chromium error: -6" by log tag chromium. In addition, My application screen always show white screen only. I follow phonegap guide for android platform. Can everybody help me, Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `WebGL` ? or can you paste the code to have an idea of why is happening?